# Angular get items value in ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

Currently im iterating through cart.items. Each item has owner's username and i want to display the owner's username and his products that i have purchased. Problem is i can only iterate through cart.items and not by owner's username so im getting duplicate cart items.

Im actually passing item from parent ngFor to child so i can get items.username.

Parent html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="cart.items.length">
    <div *ngFor="let item of cart.items">
        <chlid-component [item]="item"></child-component>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Im getting cart.items from my cartService.

child-component.component:

```
@Input() item: ICartItem;
username: string;

getUser() {
    const user = this.userService.getUser(this.item.user).subscribe(
      (user: IUser) => {
        this.username = user.username;
        this.userImage = user.image;
      }
    )
  }
```

chlid-component.html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(cart$ | async) as cart">
    <div class="avatar">
        <div class="name" routerLink="/users/{{username}}">{{username}}</div>
    </div>
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of cart.items">
    <div class="item" *ngIf="item.user == username">
        // some code here
    </div>               
</ng-container>
```

im getting username from parent's item to list item's that i bought from owner. But there is problem that i can buy multiple items from owner so it displays owner's items twice. i.e

```
User-1:    User-1:   User-2:
item1,     item1,    item3
item2,     item2
```

In child-component i'm trying to pass ngFor value to hashset and check if that username already exit's in there. How can i get item.username value and pass it to hashSet and is there a proper way to achieve that. I checked console.log and got hundreds of response for just 3 items. Can you suggest a proper way to achieve that?

Comment: This code is really incomplete, so its complicated to help. if you are able to make that component run here, even with mocks I would be able to help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-trekmd

Comment: @LuizAvila I did not use this platform, sorry if I did it wrong https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-leowg2

Comment: Is it possible that a cart has items bought by different users? it is weird that you would not have access to the user from a cart.

Comment: @LuizAvila yes, it's possible. It's kind of a leasing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to make it running according to your needs I had to group the items by username and them I used the KeyValue pipe on the `ngFor`, you can read about it here https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

here is the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a19s5s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.html)

to group the items

```
 this.cart.items.forEach((item) => {
  if (!this.groupedItems[item.username]) {
    this.groupedItems[item.username] = [];
  }
  this.groupedItems[item.username].push(item);
});
```

and the display

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groupedItems | keyvalue">
  <div class="avatar">
    <div class="name">{{ group.key }}</div>
  </div>

  <div *ngFor="let item of group.value">
    <app-child [item]="item"></app-child>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that's what i need! I was trying to do something like that in server side but it got mess. You really made it clear now